# Android Retrofit: Display in Recyclerview

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a problem on how to display my json data to a recycler view. Here is my JSON data in which I want to display the "errors" in the recycler view. I tried some ways but it always forces close.

```
{
 "result": true,
 "errors": [
   {
    "id": "e1812696024",
    "offset": 2,
    "length": 2,
    "bad": "is",
    "better": [
      "am"
        ],
    "type": "grammar"
   },
   {
    "id": "e962925648",
    "offset": 8,
    "length": 8,
    "bad": "engeneer",
    "better": [
       "engineer",
       "engender"
        ],
    "type": "spelling"
    }
 ]
}
```

Here are my codes:
Service.class (Interface)

```
public interface Service {

      @POST("/check.php")
      Call<InputResult> readErrors(@Query("userInput") String userInput,
                                   @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);
 }
```

Model classes:
InputResult.java

```
public class InputResult {

    @SerializedName("result")
    private String result;

    @SerializedName("errors")
    private List<Errors> errors;

   //getter and setter
}
```

Errors.java

```
public class Errors {

   @SerializedName("id")
   private String id;

   @SerializedName("offset")
   private int offset;

   @SerializedName("length")
   private int length;

   @SerializedName("bad")
   private String bad;

   //getter and setter
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultAdapter.ResultViewHolder>{

Context mContext;
List<Photo> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Errors> errorsList = new ArrayList<>();

public ResultAdapter (Context mContext, List<Errors> errorsList){
    this.errorsList = errorsList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public ResultViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.result_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new ResultViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ResultViewHolder resultViewHolder, int i) {

    Errors errors = errorsList.get(i);
    resultViewHolder.mNumErrorsTextView.setText(errorsList.size());
    resultViewHolder.mIdErrorTextView.setText(errors.getId());
    resultViewHolder.mLengthErrorTextView.setText(errors.getLength());
    resultViewHolder.mBadErrorTextView.setText(errors.getBad());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return errorsList.size();
}

 //Viewholder
 ...
 }
```

Fragment class:

```
ublic class Tab1Fragment_GrammarChecker extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";
private PhotoAdapter adapter;

@BindView(R.id.InputTextEditText)
EditText mInputGrammarEditText;

@BindView(R.id.ErrorsRecyclerView)
RecyclerView mErrorsRecyclerView;

List<Errors> errors = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Errors> errorArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

List<InputResult> inputResults = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<InputResult> inputResultArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public static String userInput = "I is an engeneer!";
public String apiKey = ""; 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_grammar_checker, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mErrorsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadJson();

    return view;
}

public void loadJson(){

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.textgears.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    Service serviceAPI = retrofit.create(Service.class);
    Call<InputResult> loadErrorsCall = serviceAPI.readErrors(userInput, apiKey);
    loadErrorsCall.enqueue(new Callback<InputResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<InputResult> call, Response<InputResult> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                inputResults = response.body();
                Log.i("ORIG. ARRAY SIZE", String.valueOf(inputResultArrayList.size()));
                if (inputResultArrayList != null){
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                        inputResultArrayList.add(inputResults.get(i));
                    }

                    Log.i("NEW ARRAY SIZE", String.valueOf(errorArrayList.size()));
                }
                mErrorsRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                mErrorsRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ResultAdapter1(getContext(), inputResultArrayList));
                Log.e("Fragment", response.body().toString());
                Log.e("Fragment", "SUCCESS");
            }
            else {
                Log.i("ERROR", "");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<InputResult> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("Error: ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

}
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: renelyn.austria.grammatika, PID: 32547
java.lang.ClassCastException: renelyn.austria.grammatika.Model.InputResult cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at renelyn.austria.grammatika.Tab1Fragment_GrammarChecker$1.onResponse(Tab1Fragment_GrammarChecker.java:95)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: add your logcat please, result is Boolean not String

Comment: show the log cat

Comment: @Radesh already added the logcat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the model probably should look alike the `JSON` input ...

with an `ArrayList<Error> errors` instead of `List`:

```
public class Results {

    @SerializedName("result")
    private Boolean success;

    @SerializedName("errors")
    private ArrayList<Error> errors;
    ...
}
```

and the other one (here `List` can be used to map the `String` items):

```
public class Error {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("offset")
    private Long offset;

    @SerializedName("length")
    private Long length;

    @SerializedName("bad")
    private String bad;

    @SerializedName("better")
    private List<String> better;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    ...
}
```

then it should work, without any pointless messing around:

```
Results results = response.body();
if(results.getSuccess())
    ArrayList<Error> errors = results.getErrors();
}
```

Comment: and then i will pass the arraylist errors to the adapter right?

Comment: @PatriciaOrtega when `result` is false, there won't be an `ArrayList`... but while there are records, this suffices to populate the adapter for the first time; on repeated API requests, one also has to remove previous items from the view.

Comment: i have a question, how will i display this list @SerializedName("better")
    private List<String> better; to the recyclerview as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is not your recyclerView problem , it's about your retrofit call :

You defined inputResults as List :

```
List<InputResult> inputResults = new ArrayList<>();
```

But you filled it like :

```
inputResults = response.body();
```

This not acceptable. your response as i understood is a list of InputResult but your retrofit call is single InputResult :

```
Call<InputResult>
```

You don't need to serialize or deserialize json yourself.
Just read more about retrofit and retrofit converters.
All you need to do is that initialize retrofit with GsonConverter and create another model that contains list of InputResult and pass it to retrofit call instead of InputResult to get server response without any problem.

Comment: under the input result it has two object, result and errors. the errors is a list which is i want to get and display it on my recycler view